# What makes an op-amp "high-speed"?

Tags: operational-amplifier

Very often I encounter some opamps are titled as *high-speed* in their datasheets such as [this one](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/op27.pdf).

What parameters make an op-amp high speed? What is meant by that? Is that something related to op-amp bandwidth or slew rate? And what are the criteria in that case quantitatively?

Comment: "High speed" is little more than a marketing term, like "low fat" or "improved formula"

Comment: That varies by vendor. Analog devices define it as bandwidth > 50MHz but as that is but one parameter, it is relatively meaningless except as a starting point in a particular design.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf You can delete your comments instead of just editing out the text.

Comment: need fast electrons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is customary to assume that a OPAMP is a high speed one if its *Gain-Bandwidth product* satisfies the following inequality
$$
\mathrm{GBW}=A_v\cdot\mathrm{BW}\ge 50\mathrm{MHz}\label{*}\tag{$\ast$}
$$
(see for example [here](https://www.analog.com/en/products/amplifiers/operational-amplifiers/high-speed-op-amps-bandwidth-greaterthanequalto-50mhz.html), [here](https://www.st.com/en/amplifiers-and-comparators/high-speed-op-amps-gt50-mhz.html?querycriteria=productId=SS1612) and [here](http://www.ti.com/amplifier-circuit/op-amps/high-speed/products.html)).
This is possibly is due to the fact that with such devices, you can build a video amplifier (\$\mathrm{BW}\simeq (3\div 5)\mathrm{MHz}\$) with a decent voltage gain (\$A_v\simeq 20\mathrm{dB}\$) and phase response (nearly linear, in order to avoid phase distortion). However, as remarked by Peter Smith in his comment to the question, there is not a universal agreement, and this requirement is more a way to set a limit. The OP27 cited in the question has a \$\mathrm{GBW}<10\mathrm{MHz}\$ so, to be precise, it would not fit in the category "high speed OPAMP" as defined by its producer: however, remembering that in the same family TI/Burr-Brown produced an uncompensated version, the OP37 (no more produced by TI), with \$\mathrm{GBW}\simeq63\mathrm{MHz}\$, we can understand the reason under this classification: *it identifies the capability of a given design*, possibly not shared by all its instances.
As for the parameters which identify an OPAMP as "High speed", the three following one are generally acknowledged as appropriate

- **GBW**: the requirement expressed by \eqref{*} characterizes the ability of the device to amplify signals with a bandwidth greater than \$1\mathrm{MHz}\$.
- **Settling time** \$t_s\$: to understand this parameter, remember that an OPAMP  with negative feedback and a parallel RC load behaves as a second order system (practically a RCL network). The settling time is the time when the output response to a step input voltage reach its asymptotic value usually within a given tolerance, ranging from \$0.1\%\$ and \$0.01\%\$, so the lower \$t_s\$, the faster the OPAMP. However you should be careful to compare settling times *specified to the same tolerance*: for example a \$t_s=2\mu\mathrm{s}\$ for \$0.01\%\$ *is probably lower than* a \$t_s=1\mu\mathrm{s}\$ for \$0.1\%\$ since in the first case the \$0.1\%\$ tolerance is reached probably earlier than in the latter one.
- **Slew rate** \${\mathrm{d}V}/{\mathrm{d}t}\$: this parameter express the ability of an OPAMP to reproduce fast large signals without distortion, but also its capability to drive capacitive loads. Capacities sinks a current which is proportional to the speed of variation of the voltage at their pins, so a high slew rate capability implies an output stage capable of sink/source uncommonly large currents. Therefore high speed OPAMPS have an high slew rate and a correspondingly high current output capability.

Answer (score 3):

The UA715 opamp was and still is high speed, because of the precision settling achievable. Why is such settling possible? Because the opamp silicon designers implemented (1) low input capacitance, using cascading of the input diffpair; low Cin preserves the basic opamp loop dynamics even with large resistor values; (2) widened the linear range of the input diffpair, using emitter degeneration, thus the opamp changes from high-speed-slewing into the needed linear-response-settling while still a large input error exists between Vin+ and Vin-.

Answer (score 2):

As Finbarr pointed out, there is no definitive standard for "high speed". About all you can say is that a high-speed op amp will perform well above audio frequencies (20 kHz). Assuming you want an open-loop gain of 100 at this frequency, this implies a GBW of 2 MHz or better.

So Analog Devices and TI use 50 MHz? Sure. Why not? But be aware that this has not always been so.

I'm looking at the 1990 PMI Analog Integrated Circuits Data Book, Vol 10. (PMI was a major player at the time, and was absorbed by Analog Devices in that year as well.) Looking at their OP-xx op amps, the first one to be described as "high speed" is the OP-32, with a blazing GBW of 4.5 MHz when configured for high speed (it was programmable, allowing a tradeoff of speed and operating current).

Next in the sequence was the OP-37, which was also described as "high speed", with a GBW of 63 MHz and a slew rate of 17 V/usec.

The OP-42 is described as "High Speed, Fast Settling", and has a GBW of 10 MHz. Settling time for a 10V step was about 1 usec to .01%.

That, of course, was 1990. In the early 70s, as analogsystemsrf has pointed out, the UA715 (GBW 65 MHz and 100 V/usec slew rate) was produced and labelled "high speed". As a side note, the speed was very good, but the input characteristics were, by modern standards, very bad.

So, to repeat, there is no absolute definition of high speed. It has varied with the state of the art. Both AD and TI have settled on 50 MHz GBW, probably for historical reasons as their semiconductor technology matured. Another likely reason is that a 50 MHz GBW is a very reasonable target figure for dealing with analog video signals back in the days of NTSC and PAL, where closed-loop bandwidths of a few MHz were the norm, but a fair amount of excess gain was needed to keep phase shifts to an acceptable minimum.

Comment: I am reminded of items in the 1982 National Semiconductor data book: LH003 and LH0063 "*Fast and Damn fast* buffers" for video applications.

Comment: Those were both hybrids, with no negative-feedback to improve the accuracy of buffering.

Comment: "but a fair amount of excess gain was needed to keep phase shifts to an acceptable minimum" Yes. Since phase-shifts of the chroma signal were the Chroma (color) information, the (ready-for-NTSC-video) opamp needed to ensure input-output phase tracking (down to 1_degree error?) I recall lots of datasheet bragging about these  video-capable opamps.

Comment: "the speed was very good, but the input characteristics were, by modern standards, very bad" regarding the bias currents and attendant Ibias*Rin = Verror errors ---- given the high speeds precludes large resistor values, the Ibias was not a big deal IMHO.

Comment: Another reason for sticking with 50 MHz as the transition point is that, for higher frequencies, component and layout parasitics start to become a problem. It's hardly a clear-cut issue, but it's just one more reason to stick with the accepted  boundary.